# Converting pandas dataframe to CoNLL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, conll

I have a processed dataframe which is used as a input to train a NLP model:

```
 sentence_id    words   labels
0   0            a      B-ORG
1   0            b      I-ORG
2   0            c      I-ORG
5   1            d      B-ORG
6   1            e      I-ORG
7   2            f      B-PER
8   2            g      I-PER
```

I need to convert this into ConLL text format as below:

```
a B-ORG
b I-ORG
c I-ORG

d B-ORG
e I-ORG

f B-PER
g I-PER
```

The CoNLL format is a text file with one word per line with sentences separated by an empty line. The first word in a line should be the word and the last word should be the label.

Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join both columns by space anf then in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) add last empty value with write to file:

```
df['join'] = df['words'] + ' ' + df['labels']
#alternative
#df['join'] = df['words'].str.cat(df['labels'], sep=' ')
for i, g in df.groupby('sentence_id')['join']:
    out = g.append(pd.Series({'new':np.nan}))
    out.to_csv('file.txt', index=False, header=None, mode='a')
```

Comment: It has been converted but the issue is it is adding extra space to blank line which is giving me error while training `out = g.append(pd.Series({'new':' '}))`

Comment: @Shyam - Can you try change `'new':' '` to `'new':''` ?

Comment: Its also giving output as ```den B-ORG
channel I-ORG
iii I-ORG
cable I-ORG
networks I-ORG
private I-ORG
limited I-ORG
""
bharat B-ORG
tea I-ORG
trading I-ORG
company I-ORG
limited I-ORG```

Comment: @Shyam - Understand, I hope `{'new':np.nan}` working well

Comment: Nope giving same output